# How do I return a substring from a string in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I need to implement a python like slice method in C++.
If they ask me :

```
  Slice("Hello World!",1)     output = "ello World!"
  Slice("Hello World!",0,5)   output = "Hello"
  Slice("Hello World!",0,-1)  output = "Hello World"
  Slice("Hello World!",3,-2)  output = "lo Worl"
  Slice("Hello World!",-5,-2) output = "orl"
  Slice("Hello World!",14)    output = "  "
```

if my constraints are this how would i implement this slice like method

So far I have tried creating a forloop. I tried to make an empty string and tried appended the indexes that is desired but I don't understand how.

Comment: [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)?

Comment: Seems like homework, given the very specific constraints and signature. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried creating a for loop with a bunch of if statements by creating an empty string and appending the desired index values to that but its not working

Comment: @shay You are not allocating any memory for `Ret` before your `for` loop populates `Ret`.  You need to call `Ret.resize(end-start)` before you can then use `Ret[index] = ...`. Otherwise, use `Ret += ...` instead. Also, your `for` loop should be using `i < end` instead of `i > end`.

Comment: i tried doing that but it still failed the tests

Comment: Why did you remove your code from the question? We want to see your existing attempts at solving a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) method, eg:

```
std::string Slice(const std::string &str, ssize_t start, ssize_t end)
{
    return str.substr(start, end-start);
}
```

If you can't use `substr()` (for some ridiculous reason), then you can use something more like this instead:

```
std::string Slice(const std::string &str, ssize_t start, ssize_t end)
{
    if (start >= str.length())
        return std::string();

    if (end > str.length())
        end = str.length();

    return std::string(str.c_str() + start, end - start);
}
```

Comment: i cant use substring

Comment: @shay why not? If this is for a school assignment, the requirements is information that should have been provided up front in your question. But this would be a *rediculous* limitation to use `std::string` itself without being allowed to use its functionality.

Comment: yes they asked us to implement the slice method without using the substr

Comment: @shay that is a really stupid requirement that doesn't really teach you anything useful about C++.  But whatever.  I have updated my answer with an alternative approach.

Comment: if the they ask slice("hello world!", -5, -2) the output is "orl"  should i make a for loop and state that if start is negative or end is negative then append this way

Comment: @shay once again, that is information you should have presented UP FRONT in your original question. Stop making people GUESS how your issue should be solved, TELL THEM WHAT YOU ACTUALLY NEED. Post the actual instructions, if you have to. I'm not updating my answer any further until you edit your question provide ALL of the requirements needed.

Comment: @shay you left off the part about not being allowed to use `std::string::substr()`, but OK.  I'll update my answer in a little while when I'm back in front of a computer. But why would `Slice("Hello World!",14)` output `"s"`? There is no `'s'` character in `"Hello World!"`. Did you mean `""` instead? And in python's `slice()`, passing a single index, like in `Slice("Hello World!",1)` would be a stop index, not a start index, so I would expect the output to be `"H"` instead of `"ello World!"`, I think. Do you have WRITTEN INSTRUCTIONS for this assignment?